# Documentation not visible in Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I have the following function:

```
/**
 * @param parent    ...
 * @param key   ...
 * @param isRed ...
 * ...
 */
public redBlackNode(redBlackNode parent, int key, boolean isRed) {
    ...

}
```

I can't see it (or anything else that I documented) in my Javadoc. What might be the cause of this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not seeing anything? Do you mean when you generate the HTML version? or when you hover over the function or a call to it in the IDE?

Comment: the javadoc basically looks like i didnt include the /## ... #/ block.

Comment: Looks on the web, or looks when you hover in the IDE? 
It is supposed to the stars. But do you see the text that isn't parameters?

Comment: when i hover over the function name in the ide i can the the documentation that ive written, but the html javadoc does not contain any of my comments.

Comment: by comments i mean the stuff ive written inside the /** */ block.

Comment: Can you mail me your file? And how do you generate the HTML? (udekel@cs.cmu.edu)

Answer (score 3):

Try running javadoc with the -verbose flag.  Maybe there is an error or warning occurring that you're not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just hovering? If you want to see JavaDocs for a symbol, press Ctrl+Q.